# How can I run any executable file from outside of current directory?

Tags: unix

Suppose I have an executable file a.out(Assume it'll print "hello world") in pwd like /home/My_folder/Current_folder/  and I want to run it from My_folder instead of Current_folder.
I tried it in this way :

~$ pwd

/home/My_folder

~$ cd Current_folder/a.out

~/Current_folder$

There is no show of "hello world" that means a.out is not run at all. 
All I want to run it from My_folder , not from Current _folder.

Comment: This not about programming, thus OT. However: learn the basic shell commands. You should easily find a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format would be to either start from root, `/`, or to use the current directory, `.`. These examples assume that "~$" is your prompt.

**Using `/` from anywhere on your system**

> ~$ /home/My_folder/Current_folder/a.out

**Using `.` from the `/home/My_Folder` directory**

> ~$ ./Current_folder/a.out

Answer (score 1):

~$ pwd

/home/My_folder

./Current_folder/a.out